# PyQt, check multiple check boxes

Tags: python, qt, checkbox, pyqt

I'm working on a project with pyqt and python, which I'm quite new to both. 
I have made my window design in Qt designer and now I'm working on implementing the code.

How can I make a loop to check which of a number of check boxes I have, is checked?

```
class MainUi(QtGui.QMainWindow):


def __init__(self):             
    super(MainUi, self).__init__()
    self.ui = Ui.Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.xmon = xmon2.MainUi()
    self.xmon.show()
    self.timer = XTimer(1)


    #Selection of generation to run
    self.connect(self.ui.checkBoxGen2, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.gen2Selected)
    self.connect(self.timer, QtCore.SIGNAL("tick"), self.onEventTick)
    self.connect(self.ui.checkBoxGen3, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.gen3Selected)

    #Select RS232 or CAN
    self.connect(self.ui.checkBoxCAN, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.canSelected)
    self.connect(self.ui.checkBoxRS232, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.rs232Selected)

    #Select single test or continuous test
    self.connect(self.ui.checkBoxConTest, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.conTestSelected)
    self.connect(self.ui.checkBoxSingTest, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.singTestSelected)

    #The RUN button is pressed
    self.connect(self.ui.pushButtonRun, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.runButtonPushed)

    self.connect(self.ui.pushButtonRunGen3, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.runButtonGen3Pressed)

    self.timer.start()

    if self.ui.checkBoxUnit1Gen2.ischecked():
        Unit1 = create_unit(self, 1 , self.ui.lineEditComUnit1Gen2.text()  

    if self.ui.checkBoxUnit2Gen2.ischecked():
        Unit2 = create_unit(self, 2 , self.ui.lineEditComUnit2Gen2.text()  

    if self.ui.checkBoxUnit3Gen2.ischecked():
        Unit3 = create_unit(self, 3 , self.ui.lineEditComUnit3Gen2.text()  

    if self.ui.checkBoxUnit4Gen2.ischecked():
        Unit4 = create_unit(self, 4 , self.ui.lineEditComUnit4Gen2.text()
```

So here above is part of the code I want to change. So I want to remove the if statements and replace them with a loop. For every check box that is checked a new Unit should be created with the number of the check box. For now it is just four boxes but there will be more.

Comment: If you posted your code here,maybe people can help you.

Comment: Why is  `pyq` in the title? If it is a reference to [PyQ](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Contrib/PyQ) the relationship is unclear. If it is a typo and you meant PyQT then it is superfluous and inappropriate, as you already tagged for [tag:pyqt]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, read these links to improve your question: [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Achilles I added the code if you want to have a look.

Comment: You can use `getattr` to access an attribute dynamically. For example `getattr(obj, 'name')` is the same as `obj.name`, but `'name'` can be created at runtime. In your case you could use something like: `'checkBoxUnit{}Gen2'.format(i)` to obtain the attribute name inside the loop. However it would be clear to just create a list and loop over that: `check_boxes = [self.ui.checkBoxUnit1Gen2, self.ui.checkBoxUnit2Gen2, ...]` and then `for i, check in enumerate(check_boxes, start=1): if check.ischecked(): ...`.

Comment: @Bakuriu thank you i worked for checking if the boxes are checked but i also tries to get the text from a lineEdit that is connected to the check box. I tried some think like this but can't get it to work the way i like to. `for i, check in enumerate(self.check_box_gen2, start = 1):# and line in enumerate(self.comport_gen2, start = 1):
            if check.isChecked(): 
                print getattr(self.comport_gen2[i], 'text()')` here is the code but I can't  get it to work the way i like to.

Answer (score 0):

```
#PyQt, check multiple check boxes
#Please follow any one of the below line. I hope you can achieve your result. 

#1. Find the all QCheckBox in UI.
#OR
#2. Put all QCheckBox to one QGroupBox(QCheckBox become child of this QGroupBox), then find the QCheckBox Childern of QGroupBox. 
#OR
#3. Put all QCheckBox to any layouts like QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QGridLayout (QCheckBox become child of particular Layout), then find the QCheckBox Childern of particular Layout.

#If your are not expecting this answer, sorry.
#Thanks, Subin


class MainUi(QtGui.QMainWindow):


def __init__(self):             
    super(MainUi, self).__init__()
    self.ui = Ui.Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.xmon = xmon2.MainUi()
    self.xmon.show()
    self.timer = XTimer(1)


    #Selection of generation to run
    self.connect(self.ui.checkBoxGen2, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.gen2Selected)
    self.connect(self.timer, QtCore.SIGNAL("tick"), self.onEventTick)
    self.connect(self.ui.checkBoxGen3, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.gen3Selected)

    #Select RS232 or CAN
    self.connect(self.ui.checkBoxCAN, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.canSelected)
    self.connect(self.ui.checkBoxRS232, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.rs232Selected)

    #Select single test or continuous test
    self.connect(self.ui.checkBoxConTest, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.conTestSelected)
    self.connect(self.ui.checkBoxSingTest, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.singTestSelected)

    #The RUN button is pressed
    self.connect(self.ui.pushButtonRun, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.runButtonPushed)

    self.connect(self.ui.pushButtonRunGen3, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.runButtonGen3Pressed)

    self.timer.start()




    #1. This case it will affect all the check box in your UI
    checkBoxList  = self.ui.findChildern (QtGui.QCheckBox)
    for loop in range (len(checkBoxList)) :
        if checkBoxList[loop].ischecked() :
            Unit1 = create_unit(self, loop+1 , self.ui.lineEditComUnit1Gen2.text()  


    #2. Put all QCheckBox to one QGroupBox
    checkBoxList  = self.ui.myGroup.findChildern (QtGui.QCheckBox)
    for loop in range (len(checkBoxList)) :
        if checkBoxList[loop].ischecked() :
            Unit1 = create_unit(self, loop+1 , self.ui.lineEditComUnit1Gen2.text()  


    #3. Put all QCheckBox to any layouts (QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QGridLayout)
    checkLoop    = 1
    for loop in range (self.ui.layouts.count ()) :
        currentWidget   = self.ui.layouts.itemAt(loop).widget()
        if type(currentWidget)==QtGui.QCheckBox :
              if checkBoxList[loop].ischecked() :
                    Unit1 = create_unit(self, checkLoop, self.ui.lineEditComUnit1Gen2.text()  
                    checkLoop+=1



    '''
    if self.ui.checkBoxUnit1Gen2.ischecked():
        Unit1 = create_unit(self, 1 , self.ui.lineEditComUnit1Gen2.text()  

    if self.ui.checkBoxUnit2Gen2.ischecked():
        Unit2 = create_unit(self, 2 , self.ui.lineEditComUnit2Gen2.text()  

    if self.ui.checkBoxUnit3Gen2.ischecked():
        Unit3 = create_unit(self, 3 , self.ui.lineEditComUnit3Gen2.text()  

    if self.ui.checkBoxUnit4Gen2.ischecked():
        Unit4 = create_unit(self, 4 , self.ui.lineEditComUnit4Gen2.text()  
    '''
```